# Know Your Site Monday: Which answers are most underappreciated?

Tags: discussion, trivia

Welcome to 'Know Your Site' a (hopefully) every Monday Worldbuilding trivia feature where I use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer and maybe some python parsing to find out interesting things about the site.

I will post a question on Monday, and people have until Thursday at noon to guess the answer! To be clear, using the Data Explorer to get the answer is cheating. If you use that to find the answer, feel good about your inherent superiority, but don't post it! Also, absolutely do not look at my Data Explorer profile, because that is definitely cheating.

The [populist](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/populist) badge is for having an answer that has at least twice the score of the accepted answer, while the accepted answer has a score of 11 or greater. But some posts are more populist than others. For example, the [highest voted answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/31419/23519) on the site is not accepted, so it has 319 more votes than the [accepted answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/31394/23519) (which itself is the 4th highest voted answer on the site!)

**There are six other answers that, as of the time of writing the question, have at least 100 score higher than the accepted answer. Which ones are they?**

Note, there are two answers that currently have 99 and 98 points more than the accepted answer, so don't be fooled!

Comment: By the way, I am not too sure if these answers are really "under"-appreciated. For example I prefer the answer I accepted on "Why would a staff increase the magic power of a mage?". It was given after the question disappeared from the HNQ and therefore didn't get as many upvotes as the first answer, which is the one that made it into this list. In that case the accepted answer is the "under"-appreciated answer.

Comment: @Secespitus First you answer the question in thirty minutes, then you question the witty dialogue framing the question? Next time, critique the question first, that way it will take you longer to answer :)

Comment: Will do, but it won't be long enough to give anyone else a chance to answer ;)

Comment: So is this basically a scavenger hunt?

Comment: @Aaron Yes! Come back Monday morning, I'll try to have a question that Secespitus won't answer in 30 minutes this time.

Comment: @kingledion Good luck with that, looking forward to your next question ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. [rmoore](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8118/rmoore) with 372 to 157 (215 difference): [How do you prove you're from the future?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/12395/28789)
2. [Even Mien](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/19309/even-mien) with 202 to 5 (197 difference): [Humans can now run 40 mph. How do I keep the stupid people alive?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/38705/28789)
3. [Wingman4I7](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/16021/wingman4l7) with 203 to 65 (138 difference): [Santa is Satan, but why?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/32091/28789)
4. [Mołot](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/809/mo%c5%82ot) with 144 to 16 (128 difference): [Why would a staff increase the magic power of a mage?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/95048/28789)
5. [Aify](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6453/aify) with 136 to 22 (114 difference): [How do you assassinate someone who is protected by precognitive people?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/37243/28789)
6. [Doomfrost](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/39814/doomfrost) with 141 to 32 (109 difference): [How can a race of eldritch abominations help humanity?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/88894/28789)

Bonus:

- 99 difference: [Andon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/34371/andon) with 122 to 23: [How do I keep my slaves happy?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/75002/28789)
- 98 difference: [Oddthinking](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/13369/oddthinking) with 160 to 62: [Would intelligent life evolve any other body plan than humanoid?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/25219/28789)

Comment: Wait it isn't thursday yet!

Comment: @dot_Sp0T Feel free to "guess" differently ;)

Comment: have you become a [*fruit*](https://vimeo.com/21747491) commercial?

Comment: Geez, how did you do that so quickly without SEDE?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I suspect doping. I'm going to have to ask Secespitus to mail me a urine sample.

Comment: @MonicaCellio For the most part I remembered them, for example because one of them is on my highest voted question. For the others I made some guesses looking through the highest voted questions (there are not so many questions where 100 net score difference for the answers is possible).

Comment: @kingledion Do I have to do that every time I solve one of these trivia quizzes before half the Meta regulars have seen the question?

Comment: Oh. Wow. I'm surprised I ended up on this list.

Comment: @Mołot That's my fault for not accepting your very good answer to my staff question ;)